# How to make an if statement ignore a var if 0?

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to check if a variable is greater than x, unless it is 0.

so for example.

```
<?php
$max_n=10;//user setting maximum number of loops, infinite? choose 0.


//the problem is that 0 is the smallest number, so the loop stops immediately

for ($x = 0; $x <= $max_n; $x++) {
    $total_n=$x;
}

//if total number exceeds max amount of numbers, do something
if(1==1 || $total_n > $max_n )
{
    die('Total number is greater than max numbers!');
}

?>
```

Obviously infinite loops are a bad idea, but that is not the point.

How do I make the if statement ignore the max_n if max_n =0

Comment: Remove the `1==1 ||` (which makes the if statement ALWAYS true) and it works as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [continue;](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) statement to skip to the next record on certain criteria.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= $max_n; $x++) {
  if($max_n===0){
    continue;
  }
    $total_n=$x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//if total number exceeds max amount of numbers, do something

if($max_n != 0 && $total_n > $max_n )
{
    die('Total number is greater than max numbers!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
<?php
$max_n=10;//user setting maximum number of loops, infinite? choose 0.


//the problem is that 0 is the smallest number, so the loop stops immediately

for ($x = 0; $x <= $max_n; $x++) {
    $total_n=$x;
}

//if total number exceeds max amount of numbers, do something
if(1==1 || ( $total_n > 0 && $total_n > $max_n ) )
{
    die('Total number is greater than max numbers!');
}
?>
```